# Creating Excel file using PhpSpreadsheet with default data using Laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel-5, phpspreadsheet

I am trying to download excel file with pre-populated data using PhpSpreadsheet in laravel. But I am got empty file downloaded.Here`s my code.

```
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx;

$spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet();
$sheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();
$sheet->setCellValue('B1','testing');

$writer = new Xlsx($spreadsheet);
$filename = 'tessa';

header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="'. $filename .'.Xlsx"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');

$writer->save($filename);
```

I tried dd($sheet)  Here how it looks,it contains my data;

[image]

The file downloaded but empty file.Can any one tell me how to solve the issue?

Answer (score 2):

You don't really need to set those headers. But if you must, edit `filename` to:

```
$filename = 'tessa.xlsx';
```

Comment: I just tried but no file downloaded and empty white page

Comment: Did you download the whole library? Do you have this line above your code? `require 'vendor/autoload.php';`..?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change

```
$writer->save($filename);
```

to:

```
$writer->save('php://output');
```